# Trigger or Stored Procedure?

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Let's say I have two tables, foo and bar:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
   foo_id    serial    NOT NULL,
   count     integer   NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(foo_id)
   );

CREATE TABLE bar(
   bar_id    serial    NOT NULL,
   foo_id    SERIAL    NOT NULL REFERENCES foo(foo_id),
   PRIMARY KEY(bar_id)
   );
```

When something gets inserted into `bar` with a given `foo_id`, the corresponding record in `foo` should have its count incremented. How exactly do I go about doing this? I'm fairly new to databases in general.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(1, 0);
INSERT INTO bar VALUES(1, 1);
```

At the second line, `count` should be incremented at the record for `foo_id = 1`.

I also need to the count decremented on a delete, but I'm sure that's pretty similar to incrementing on insert.

Answer (score 1):

Follow your `INSERT` statement with:

```
UPDATE bar SET count = (count+1) WHERE foo_id=1
```

And on delete:

```
UPDATE bar SET count = (count-1) WHERE foo_id=1
```

Comment: .. and wrap all these statements in a transaction, with good error trapping and handling.

Answer (score 1):

Recognising that this count is denormalised, and assuming you need it for some purpose that can't be obtained on-the-fly at run time, such as a `COUNT()` or `EXISTS()`, I would suggest you use a trigger on `bar`.  More specifically, three triggers, one each for update, insert and delete since each will have a different effect on `foo`.  Note, too, that you may need equivalent triggers on other bar-like tables which also have a foreign key pointing back to `foo`, depending on what your specific needs are.

In this case a trigger has the advantage of separating "proper" business rules (which should be in a stored procedure) from system optimisation.  The former can be maintained by developers without the latter cluttering the code.  Secondly, there is less risk that the optimisation code is compromised during a code change.  Third, future SPs cannot forget to implement this optimisation or choose not to implement it.  The trigger is there for all usage of the table.  If there is a case when the count should not be updated that can be made explicit in the trigger code and well commented there for all to see.

Comment: While I agree with you, I have to add a con: with many of these triggers it will be very hard to follow what happens on a simple `INSERT`.  I used to spend much time debugging funny behaviour, partly induced by my denormalization triggers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to question why you are storing a count on the foo table. You will be able to retrive the number of bar records referencing any given foo_id at a later date by using SELECT COUNT(*)...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to retrieve the count by running

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo 
INNER JOIN bar
ON foo.foo_is = bar.foo_id
```